# MVC3 - QueryString NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Thanks for reading this.

Want to pass data from querystring to an action; the URL

MyController/MyAction?lob=a

Have tried this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
        var model = new SModel();
        model.lob = Request.QueryString["lob"];
        return View(model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction(string lob)
{
        var model = new SModel();
        model.lob = lob;
        return View(model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection values)
{
        var model = new SModel();
        model.lob = values["lob"];
        return View(model);
}
```

"lob" is always null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only have the one MyAction method in your controller.

You can also remove the `[HttpGet]`

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string lob)
{
    var model = new SModel();
    model.lob = lob;
    return View(model);
}
```

If you want to have a second MyAction for post, add `[HttpPost]` to it, so the controller can determine which method to use.

Comment: yes; I do have HttpPost.
I guess removing 'get' works. thanks!